# Custom object lookup to Case

Tags: lightning, custom-object, case

I have a custom object that will contain the bulk (or all) of 100+ fields for a new lightning app. Also plan to associate the custom object with a new Case standard record at the same time the custom object is created. Currently placing a lookup field on the custom object to the Case record to establish the relationship. Eventually we will implement email-to-case and possibly escalation rules for the Case. Are there any issues with establishing the case lookup from the custom object instead of from Case to custom object? I can't see any loss of Case functionality and we already have many lookup fields on the Case obj so trying to limit that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, it should not be a problem, especially if your Case object is already pretty large. The only real difference is how you'll have to write your queries if you decide to go that route, but it's not a big issue either way.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox. Thanks again for the second pair of eyes here.